# telegram bot online/offline status question

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram, tracking

Is it possible to track online or offline user via telegram bot knowing his id.

```
bot.command('check_status', async (ctx) => {
}
```

I am writing a TG bot and my tutor said to me the task "track user's status" I have them id and can't find on internet any aproach to this task.

Comment: I think that is not possible because Telegram API does not provide that functionality for privacy reasons

Comment: Why are you think so? If telegram show it in chat... Moreover, they interacted with bot and bot api give access to id and username of the user. I can look at it manually online but I can’t look it through the code, it’s so a little stupid

Comment: While users may see other users' online status in a chat, the availability of this information via APIs for third-party developers may be restricted due to privacy reasons